# Delete all lines until a specific line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have to edit a lot of source codes similar to each other.

```
random blah
 random blah
blah
<table style="width: 232px; font-size: small;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">....
```

What I want to do is to delete lines until table tag. I think I can do it with Regex search but I couldnt write the regex pattern.
Thank you

Comment: Nice question, but I don't think you can do it. I couldn't find how to enable multi-line. `(?m)` inside the regex doesn't seem to work. Maybe you should ask people to give you tested solutions, because theoretical ones are useless.

Comment: The problem may be that languages allow you to only do it once but n++ doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go through multiple steps to do what you stated above:

1. Go to the replace window, select the "extended" mode, and in the "find what" field type in "`\r\n`" and replace them with: "`LINEBREAK`" (theres a space after 'LINEBREAK'). Click on replace all.
2. Go to the replace window again, select the "regular expression" mode, and in the "find what" field type in `"(.*)(.*)(<table)(.*)(>)(.*)(.*)"` and in the replace with field, type in "`\2\3\4\5`". Click on replace all.
3. Now go to replace window again, select elect the "extended" mode, and in the "find what" field type in "`LINEBREAK`" (theres a space after 'LINEBREAK') and replace them with: "`\r\n`". Click on replace all.

Notepad++ doesn't support multi line regex, which makes it hard to do what you wanted to do without going through the steps given above.

Comment: Thank you so much, It solved my problem mostly, after small tweak it will be perfect..

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
(^.*$\n)*<table(.+)>
```

First group will match all lines before your table tag %)